# How do you change the icon for an automator app?

Tags: automator, macos-high-sierra

I have created a simple application for my Mac using Automator. I am trying to change its icon from the default robot icon, but anything I try does not work. I have tried copy-pasting the image I want using the Get Info technique, but that didn't work. I also converted the image I want as my icon to a .icns file and put it in the resources folder inside the package contents folder for the app. I also renamed that icon to AutomatorApplet.icns. This technique did not work either. Are there any other techniques I can try, or am I simply doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The copy-paste technique actually works. The one thing I realized I missed is to select the image. You need to hit command-a to "select all" before you can copy the image you want to use as your icon. Then to paste the image onto the app/file you want to have the image as an icon for, just select the item and hit command-i. The get info panel opens and you will need to click on the icon on the top left. Hit command-v and your new image should be used as an icon.